# Type hints for PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, static-typing

How can I use type hints with PyTorch? If I inspect the class for the model returned, I get `models.common.AutoShape`. However, `models` shows up as unknown.

```
import torch

model : models.common.AutoShape = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)
```

I also want to explicitly type the results.

Comment: For an example, and explanation why it might not be so useful, see [Some Thoughts About Using Type Hints With PyTorch](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2022/01/25/some-thoughts-about-using-type-hints-with-pytorch/)

Comment: The author suggests that he doesn't use type hints because "aren’t any good code checkers", so he just uses comments. I find that opinion odd.

Comment: An additional use for type hints is that an IDE can make code suggestions if the type is declared.